# this.router.navigate function doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I'm using Angular 8 and faced some problems with routing when I'm using lazy-loaded child modules.

> app-routing.module.ts

```js
...
const routes: Routes = [
   {
      path: :id,
      component: ParentComponent,
      children: [
         { path: 'child', loadChildren: './child.module#ChildModule' }
      ]
   }
]
...
```

> child-routing.module.ts

```js
...
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'child1', component: Child1Component },
   { path: 'child2', component: Child2Component }
]
...
```

Now, we have routing in these ways.
foo.com/123/child/child1 -> Child1Component
foo.com/123/child/child2 -> Child2Component

Here, I tried to navigate to foo.com/123/child/child2 inside Child1Component.
I was thinking child module is apart from app module and it's lazy loaded so this code will be working correctly.

> child2.component.ts

```js
...
constructor(private router: Router) {}

...
this.router.navigate(['child/child2']);
...
```

But once I launched the application, it is navigated to foo.com/child/child2.
I was expecting foo.com/123/child/child2.

If I make these changes, it's working as expected.

> child2.component.ts

```js
...
private parentId;
constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.route.parent.parent.params.subscribe((params) => {this.parentId = params.id});
}

...
this.router.navigate([this.parentId, 'child', 'child2']);
...
```

It's getting parentId from the URL inside the component and navigate using it.
But I don't like this approach because it's not scalable.
If I change the Route Param name or add some more routing params, I have to update the child components for routing as well.

Is there any better approach for handling routing in child components defined on child module lazy-loaded?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate)

> Navigate based on the provided array of commands and a starting point. If no starting route is provided, the navigation is absolute.

as well per [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation),

> The router supports directory-like syntax in a link parameters list to
>   help guide route name lookup:
>
> ./ or no leading slash is relative to the current level.
>
> ../ to go up one level in the route path.
>
> You can combine relative navigation syntax with an ancestor path. If
>   you must navigate to a sibling route, you could use the ../
>   convention to go up one level, then over and down the sibling route
>   path.

So you can work with relative routes, as per Angular example

```
this.router.navigate(['../', { id: crisisId, foo: 'foo' }], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

Where `this.route` is an instance of ActivatedRoute.